# Exception when attempted to run MVC Music Store after including SampleData.cs in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting an exception when I attempt to run MVC Music Store app listed in http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/64379 . As soon as I included `SampleData.cs` in the Models folder and make some changes to include this model, I get an ArgumentException, Illegal characters in path. Any similar experiences?  Can someone help in resolving this as I am stuck with this for a while now.

thanks

Any inputs please

Exact code is below,

```
public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

I added `SampleDat.cs` file to my Model. It is a huge file, I am listing out only a part of it here.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Data.Entity;

 namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
 {
     public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MusicStoreEntities>
     {
        protected override void Seed(MusicStoreEntities context)
        {
            var genres = new List<Genre>
            {
                new Genre { Name = "Rock" },
                new Genre { Name = "Jazz" }
            };

            var artists = new List<Artist>
            {
                new Artist { Name = "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra" },
                new Artist { Name = "Aaron Goldberg" }
            };

            new List<Album>
            {
                new Album { Title = "The Best Of Men At Work", 
                            Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Rock"), 
                            Price = 8.99M,
                            Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Men At Work"),
                            AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif"
                          },
                new Album { Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I",
                            Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Classical"),
                            Price = 8.99M,
                            Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra"),
                            AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif"
                          }
            }.ForEach(a => context.Albums.Add(a));
        }
    }
}
```

I have set a Data Initializer in `Global.asax`,

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MvcMusicStore.Models.SampleData());
}
```

In my Controller, `StoreController.cs` I am doing

```
var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();
```

and get the follwing exception.

> Exception is "Illegal characters in path."
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> public ActionResult Index()
> {
>     var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();
>     return View(genres);
> }
> ```
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.]
> System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path) +126
> System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength) +145
> System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path) +46
> System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path) +33
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeUtil.DemandForPermission(String filename, FileIOPermissionAccess permissions) +71
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase() +1217
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 timeOut, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +288
> System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +84
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseOperations.Create(ObjectContext objectContext) +35
> System.Data.Entity.Database.Create() +70
> System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +477
> System.Data.Entity.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializerInternal>b__0(DbContext c) +143
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass5.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__3() +59
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +101
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +260
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +31
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +147
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +276
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +112
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +41
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +34
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +148
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +33
> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +91
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315
> System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
> MvcMusicStore.Controllers.StoreController.Index() in C:\My Projects\MvcMusicStore\MvcMusicStore\Controllers\StoreController.cs:16
> lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +96
> System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
> System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
> System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
> System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
> System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
> System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
> System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
> System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
> ```

Comment: Any help to resolve this exception???

Comment: @user152884 What is the exception you are getting, and also post the relevant code to what u are doing.

Comment: Added code, exception details and stack trace

Comment: I typed `Data Directory` instead of `DataDirectory` in the connection string. When I corrected that I was able to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

the soulution is on this post
[http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/discussions/359070][1]

be sure that the MusicStoreEntities implements DbContext as:

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I went through this tutorial, I got this error because of a typo in the lines I added to my Web.Config file. Make sure your `<connectionString>` node looks exactly like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I typed `Data Directory` instead of `DataDirectory` in the connection string. When I corrected that I was able to move forward.